# Conditionally declare directive in Angular 2 ngModule

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

In Angular 2 I would like to declare a directive inside my ngModule only if a global javascript variable is set to true (debug boolean).

This was working when compiling with tsc:

```
declare let isDebug: boolean;
let dependencyArray : any[] = [];

if ('undefined' !== typeof isDebug && isDebug) {
  dependencyArray.push(DebugDirective);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent].concat(dependencyArray),
  imports: []
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

However it seems than the ngc compiler (AOT compilation) does not accept function call in module files. The following error is thrown by ngc.

> Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function

I have found the various threads explaining how to use a factory with an exported function for providers (e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262) but I have not found how to do the same for the declaration array.

How can I solve the issue for the module declaration?

Answer (score 0):

How about exporting a function (returning an any[]) and the declaration directive pointing to the function reference.

Comment: I have not tried for a while and I should check how it has evolved but at the time this was not working.